# Error: Cannot perform parcel split operations

Tags: saex

We are using Saex tools for Parcel operations. While splitting parcels, we can perform all the operations successfully except the last one. when performing split parcel operation we get `Error: Cannot perform parcel split operations`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not parcel key in that parcel. So first fill proper attribute in parcel layer then generate parcel key and perform parcel split.

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur if the underlying database has been used for a long time. try to import the database into a new one and the problem should be solved.